# How to Copy/Clone a Virtual Environment from Webserver

Tags: django-views

I have an existing Python django Project running in Web Server. Now the client needs to make some changes in the existing code. So I need to set it up in my Local Machine. All the packages needed for this project is installed in a Virtual environment. How can I copy or clone this virtual environment to my Local machine to run this Project.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy - say your server virtualenv is inside `~/example.org/_env/` and your local project dir is `~/Projects/example`:

You activate the environment:

```
cd ~/example.org/_env/
. _env/bin/activate
```

Then you freeze current env:

```
pip freeze > pip-requirements.txt
```

Then you download that file to your machine and rebuild the environment:

```
cd ~/Projects/example
virtualenv _env
pip install --use-mirrors -r pip-requirements.txt
```

It is also possible that your project already has pip-requirements.txt file, so you could just ignore step one if that's the case.

If you have no virtualenv binary on your machine, you can install by using, for example:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

which will install it system-wide